# tsql: how to export query results to .csv?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to export my query results to a .csv file (local). I have been googling for a while now...can't seem to find a nice simple example out there.  Thanks for the help.

Example: 
"select top 3 * from table"  to -----> "c:\data\test_data.csv"

Comment: This is usually done by the SQL client. Which one are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Dev.  I want to do this programmaticly  and run it as a job.

Comment: There are many, many [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+export+csv) on this site about exporting data from SQL Server to csv. What solutions have you already tried and what specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command line [`bcp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or SQL Server Integration Services to do that

```
bcp "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM test.dbo.table1" queryout c:\temp\table1.csv -c -t, -T -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```